# Converting JSON to array in Swift 2

Tags: ios, arrays, json, uitableview, swift2

I need to build `Arrays` for a Grouped `UITableView`, with a Title and Detail line in each table cell. I've got my json output from the server putting it in the right shape to iterate through the `UITableViewDataSource` methods. But what's the simplest way to convert these to a readable array that those `UITableView` functions can reference?

The headings array is for the Group headings, so it's just a one-dimensional array. I can iterate that. The titles and details arrays are both two dimensional. I can't figure out how to do that in Swift.

```
"headings":["Tuesday, August 16, 2016","Wednesday, August 17, 2016","Thursday, August 18, 2016","Friday, August 19, 2016","Saturday, August 20, 2016","Sunday, August 21, 2016","Monday, August 22, 2016","Tuesday, August 23, 2016","Wednesday, August 24, 2016","Thursday, August 25, 2016","Friday, August 26, 2016","Saturday, August 27, 2016","Sunday, August 28, 2016","Monday, August 29, 2016","Tuesday, August 30, 2016","Wednesday, August 31, 2016","Thursday, September 1, 2016","Friday, September 2, 2016","Saturday, September 3, 2016","Sunday, September 4, 2016","Monday, September 5, 2016","Tuesday, September 6, 2016","Wednesday, September 7, 2016","Thursday, September 8, 2016","Friday, September 9, 2016","Saturday, September 10, 2016","Sunday, September 11, 2016","Monday, September 12, 2016","Tuesday, September 13, 2016","Wednesday, September 14, 2016","Thursday, September 15, 2016","Friday, September 16, 2016"],

"titles":[["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Sandy Primmell","Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Sandy Primmell","Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson","Joe Johnson"],["Sandy Primmell","Joe Johnson"],["Mark Greene","Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Sandy Primmell","Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Sandy Primmell","Joe Johnson"],["Mark Greene","Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"],["Joe Johnson"]],

"details":[["OFF"],["OFF"],["Gregory","OFF"],["Gregory"],["OFF"],["OFF"],["OFF"],["Weekday Rounders","OFF"],["Weekday Rounders","Night Owls"],["Gregory","OFF"],["Gregory","OFF"],["OFF"],["OFF"],["OFF"],["Gregory"],["Gregory","OFF"],["Gregory"],["Gregory","OFF"],["Gregory","OFF"],["OFF"],["OFF"],["OFF"],["OFF"],["OFF"],["OFF"],["OFF"],["OFF"],["OFF"],["OFF"],["OFF"],["OFF"],["OFF"]]
```

*UPDATE*

Here's my Alamofire async function that grabs the data:

```
manager.request(.POST, getRouter(), parameters:["dev": 1, "app_action": "schedule", "type":getScheduleType(), "days_off":getScheduleDaysOff(), "period":getSchedulePeriod(), "begin_date":getScheduleBeginDate(), "end_date":getScheduleEndDate()])
        .responseString {response in
            print(response)
            var json = JSON(response.result.value!);
// what I'm missing
   }
```

Comment: how did you get that data from server? some framework have built in JSON parser that will allow you to easily create those array

Comment: @Thom try my answer and let me know if you have some problems

Comment: @Thom ok, if it works for you mark my answer as right, I would appreciate it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, You can use JSON parsing libraries like [Argo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo) or [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON), which were created to simplify the JSON parsing. They are both well tested and will handle edge cases for you, like missing parameters in the JSON responses etc.

### An example using Argo:

Assuming the JSON response has this format (from [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/list))

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 2960784075,
      "id_str": "2960784075",
      ...
    }
}
```

#### 1- Create a Swift class to represent the response

Note that `Response` is a class that contains an array of `User` which is another class not shown here, but you get the point.

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let users: [User]
    let next_cursor_str: String

    static func decode(j: JSON) -> Decoded<Response> {
        return curry(Response.init)
            <^> j <|| "users"
            <*> j <| "next_cursor_str"
    }
}
```

#### 2- Parse the JSON

```
//Convert json String to foundation object
let json: AnyObject? = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])

//Check for nil    
if let j: AnyObject = json {
  //Map the foundation object to Response object
  let response: Response? = decode(j)
}
```

### An example using Swifty

As explained in the [official documentation](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#initialization):

#### 1- Convert JSON string to SwiftyJSON object

```
if let dataFromString = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
    let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
}
```

#### 2- Access specific element

If data is an array then use the index

```
//Getting a double from a JSON Array
let name = json[0].double
```

If data is a dictionary then use the key

```
//Getting a string from a JSON Dictionary
let name = json["name"].stringValue
```

#### 2'- Loop over the elements

Array

```
//If json is .Array
//The `index` is 0..<json.count's string value
for (index,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
    //Do something you want
}
```

Dictionary

```
//If json is .Dictionary
for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
   //Do something you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How about with Swifty? I looked there but couldn't successfully implement anything.

Comment: @Thom Referenced the important pieces from the documentation. Notice that with Argo you create a class and then let Argo map the JSON data to your class, but in Swifty, you don't create a class, but you do the mapping yourself.

Comment: This is terrific. Thank you. I am using SwiftyJson and was able to use it to iterate through the one-dimensional one no problem. Is a dictionary basically the JS object equiv?

Comment: You mean equivalent to the JS dictionary? Yes, it is :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this function:

```
func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    if let data = text.dataUsingEncodi‌​ng(NSUTF8StringEncodi‌​ng) {
        do {
            return try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

and then you can read the array like this:

```
if let dict = convertStringToDictionary(jsonText) {
    let array = dict["headings"] as? [String]
}
```

Comment: I put the function into a Swift file and it gave me two errors:
On line 2: Value of type 'String' has no member 'data'
On line 4: Use of unresolved identifier 'JSONSerialization'

Comment: @Thom try this: let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

Comment: That fixed the first error. Still getting the one on line 4.

Comment: @Thom replace JSONSerialization with NSJSONSerialization

Comment: I tried that but then it said that jsonObject is not a member of NSJSONSerialization

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121063/discussion-between-saintthread-and-thom).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are getting `Dictionary` from json and each key contain `Array`, you can try something like this, first declare one `Dictionary` instance and use that with `TableViewDataSource` methods.

```
var response = [String: AnyObject]()

do {
     self.response = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
     print(dic)
}
catch let e as NSError {
     print(e.localizedDescription)
}
```

Now inside `tableView` methods

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if let arr = self.response["headings"] as? [String] {
        return arr.count
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let headings = self.response["headings"] as! [String]
    return headings[Int]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let arr = self.response["titles"] as? [[String]] {
        return arr[Int].count
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let titles = self.response["titles"] as! [[String]]
    let details = self.response["details"] as! [[String]]       
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! EmployeeCell
    cell.mainLabel?.text = titles[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.detailLabel?.text = details[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: What am I putting in `data!`? I'm getting errors in your do/catch.

Comment: In your api call you are getting `NSData` object, that you need to pass with that method, If you don't get it add the code in question that you have used to call api.

Comment: after this line `var json = JSON(response.result.value!);` add line like this self.response = json as! [String: AnyObject]` and then reload the tableView.

Comment: Have you try like i said?

Comment: Are you saying that I don't need the do/catch?

Comment: You are not getting nsdata, You are directly getting response so no need of try and catch.

Comment: WOuldn't the `numberOfRowsInSection` function need to be something like:  `return titles[indexPath.section].count` ?

Comment: No i am correct check properly `numberOfRowsInSecti‌on` has no parameter indexPath

Comment: Yeah I saw that. Just couldn't figure out how it knows which set of titles to count.

Comment: The numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection functions are erroring out with unexpected nils at `return self.response["headings"]!.count`. I think it's because it's building the table before the async gets done and refreshes.

Comment: Yes. Your solution didn't get me all the way there, but it helped a lot. I did finally get something worked out that works. I will post it soon as I can. I'm not sure whose answer to select because I used bits and pieces from several answers to patch my solution together.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using AlamofireObjectMapper. The library lets you you map objects from json easily and if combined with Alamofire can cast and return your object on the server response. The object mapping itself should look like this in your case

```
class CustomResponseClass: Mappable {
    var headings: [String]?

    required init?(_ map: Map){

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        headings <- map["headings"]
   }
}
```

This way you decouple the logic of mapping and parsing json from your tableViewController.

[AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper)

Comment: Thanks. Checking this out.

Comment: @Thom In case you found your solution can you please accept one of the above answers please.

Comment: I used bits and pieces from multiple answers but I chose the one that I think was the closest to my final solution.